# dltk was required but not found while installing pdt-eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I tried to install PDT-Eclipse by click `Help` - `Install New Software` in Eclipse and typed in the following link(official PDT link): http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest/, but I got the following errors:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.6.0.201509151953 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 3.6.0.201509151953)
  Missing requirement: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.6.0.201509151953 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 3.6.0.201509151953) requires 'org.eclipse.dltk.core.feature.group 5.3.0' but it could not be found
```

How to solve the problem? By the way, I've already checked `Contact all update sites during install to find required software`

Comment: Using the `latest` update site means you are using bleeding edge code and will need to find the latest update sites for other components such as dltk. Normally you should stick to the current release which should be in the list for your main Eclipse update site.

Answer (score 1):

You need latest DLTK : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/latest

Or unofficial mirror with PDT, DLTK and PDT extensions: http://p2.pdt-extensions.org/

**Edit**

Latest stable PDT is 3.5, latest stable DLTK is 5.2.1. Your error is about PDT nightly. You probably have http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly repository.

Use http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/latest-nightly or unofficial http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem with DLTK 5.9.
The simplest solution was to update Eclipse, you can find how to do that here:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F